What is wrong with this proof that a linear, bounded, time invariant operator on $L_p$ must be a convolution?
I'm trying to understand if this is true and how to prove it, "If $T$ is a bounded, time invariant operator on $L_p(\mathbb{R})$, then $T$ is a convolution operator.''
Here's an attempt at a proof that seems to work.

Assume ( T ) is time-invariant, i.e.,  for any shift ( a>0 ), ( T(S_a f) = S_a (T f) ).
Let $\phi_n$ be an approximation to the identity (see previous lemma), with the added condition that $\|\phi_n\|_p = 1$, e.g., $\phi_n = n^{1/p}$ on $[\pm 1/(2n)]$.
Since $T$ is bounded (continuous), we see that for any $f\in L_p, \|T(f*\phi_n) - T(f)\|_p \to 0.$
Next,  since $\|T \phi_n\|\leq  \|T\|$, we can apply Banach-Alaoglu Theorem, and find a subsequence $n_k$ such that $T\phi_{n_k}$ converges weakly to a function $h\in L_p$.
That is, for all $g\in L_q$ with $q$ conjugate exponent to $p$, we have
$\langle h, g\rangle = \lim_k \langle T\phi_{n_k}, g\rangle = \lim_k \langle \phi_{n_k}, T^* g \rangle = \overline{T^*g} (0) $ if $T^*g$ is continuous at $t = 0$.
Finally,
\begin{align*}
    T(f*\phi_n)(t) &= T \int_\tau \phi_n(t-\tau)f(\tau)d\tau \\
     &= \int_\tau f(\tau) T (\phi_n(t-\tau)) d\tau \text{  --- by linearity}\\
     &= \int_\tau f(\tau) TS_\tau(\phi_n(t))d\tau \\
     & = \int_\tau f(\tau) S_\tau T(\phi_n(t))d\tau  \text{  --- by time invariance}\\
     & = f*(T\phi_n)
\end{align*}
Letting $n\to \infty$ we have $Tf(t) = f*h$.

So if this proof is true, then we proved there is some $h\in L_p$ with $\|h\|_p = \|T\phi_n\|_p \leq \|T\|$ and such that $\langle h, g\rangle = \bar{g}(0)$ for continuous functions $g$.
I don't think such a function $h$ can exist. If so it would be the Dirac $\delta$, right?
If so, what is wrong with this proof?
Is it true that $T$ bounded, linear, time invariant means it is a limit of convolutions?

The problem is that (as you noted by the conclusion!) your approximation of the identity is not such. The usual argument with mollifiers requires the function $\phi$ to be in $L^1$. And in $L^1$ the argument cannot possibly work because there is no Banach-Alaoglu; or there is, in a sense, but you get a measure and not necessarily a function $h$.
When $p>1$, you don't get a mollifier. Mollifiers for $p>1$ are unbounded.
Also, the first step in your  argument is valid, but possibly not by the reason you state (linearity); it is a lot more than that. In general, you cannot treat the functions inside the integral as functions where you can apply your operator. Let us make a simple counterexample. Let $Tf=1_{[1,2]}\,f$. Put $h=1_{[0,1]}$, and
$$\tag1
g(t)=(h*f)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t-\tau)\,f(\tau)\,d\tau=\int_{t-1}^tf.
$$
Then $(Tg)(1)=\int_0^1f$. But $Th=1_{\{1\}}$, and so $Th*f=0$ for all $t$.
Here is another example. Let $(Tf)(t)=f(t^2)$ and put $g=h*k$. Then
$$
(Tg)(t)=g(t^2)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t^2-s)\,k(s)\,ds, 
$$
while
$$
(Th)*k(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h((t-s)^2)\,k(s)\,ds.
$$
Having said all the above, the first step in your argument is valid; and that's because $T$ is not only linear and bounded, but translation invariant for all translations. What happens is this. You want $Tg$, where $g=h*k$. We have
\begin{align}
(h*k)(t)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t-s)\,k(s)\,ds
=\lim_N\int_{-N}^Nh(t-s)\,k(s)\,ds\\[0.2cm]
&=\lim_N\lim_M\sum_{j=1}^M h(t-s_j)k(s_j)\Delta_j\\[0.2cm]
&=\lim_N\lim_M\sum_{j=1}^M h_j(t)k(s_j)\Delta_j,
\end{align}
where $h_j=S_{s_j}h$. Now the Riemann sum is written as a linear combination of the functions $h_j$, and  the linearity and continuity of $T$ give us
$$
(T(h*k))(t)=\lim_N\lim_M\sum_{j=1}^M (Th_j)(t)k(s_j)\Delta_j.
$$
And because $TS_{s_j}=S_{s_j}T$, we have that $(Th_j)(t)=(Th)(t-s_j)$. Then
\begin{align}
(T(h*k))(t)&=\lim_N\lim_M\sum_{j=1}^M (Th)(t-s_j)k(s_j)\Delta_j\\[0.2cm]
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (Th)(t-s)\,k(s)\,ds
\end{align}
Finally, the article by Lars Hörmander: Estimates for translation invariant operators in Lp spaces, Acta Math.104 (1960), 93–140 (link here if you have access) states that translation invariant operators in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ are given by convolution against a distribution.
Another link to the Hörmander paper

Could you give the full reference to the article. The link points to something inaccessible to non-AMS members.

The article is Hörmander, Lars. Estimates for translation invariant operators in Lp spaces. Acta Math.104(1960), 93–140.

So the problem here is that if $p>1$, then even for $g\in L_q$ and continuous at $t = 0$, we cannot conclude that $\langle \phi_n, g\langle = \int_[\pm 1/2n] n^{1/p} g = g(0)$, because $\int \phi_n  = n^{1/p - 1}\neq 1$. Moreover, if $n=1$, then the dual space is the set of bounded Borel measures, so we don't get a function with which to convolve.
Q: I think my proof that $T(f*\phi) = f*(T\phi)$ has correctly and exactly where linearity is needed and where time invariance is needed (I agree we need both), but your response indicates that that portion of the proof is incorrect?

So to correct this proof, would this work: 1.  consider $T$ restricted to $L_1\cap L_p$, a dense subset, 2. use the argument above to show that $Tf = f*d\mu$ for a finite Borel measure $\mu$, 3. use continuity to extend to $L_p$. Conclusion, $T$ is bounded, linear, and time invariant $\implies \exists$ finite Borel measure $\mu$ such that $T(f)(t)  = \int f(t-\tau)d\mu(\tau)$. ?

As explained in my answer, you use the time invariance in your second equal sign, where you wrote "linearity". I still don't think your argument works for $p>1$, because you don't get bounded mollifiers for the $p$-norm, so there is never a convergent sequence to start with. At least not via an Alaoglu argument. Hörmander's paper, which I haven't read, seems to imply that you can get $T\phi_n$ to somehow converge to a distribution.

I disagree that I am using time invariance of $T$ in the second equality. It may be confusing notation. I used $T(\phi(t-\tau))$ for $TS_\tau \phi$ which I meant to be different than $T\phi (t-\tau) = S_\tau T\phi$. In any case, I think we are on the same page.
As for Hömander's paper, I found and included a link that doesn't require access to mathscinet. Looks like he uses $S$, the set of infinitely differentiable functions, which is dense in $L_p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ and extends to $L_p$ via continuity of $T$ (although the proof is different).

No, it's not a notation thing. You cannot use just linearity and continuity to introduce the operator inside the integral as you did. As explained in the answer (with two counterexamples and a proof), that only works because $T$ is time-invariant.

I really appreciate you replying to teach me this. I still don't agree (perhaps I'm misunderstanding something). To use your proof with Riemann sums: "the linearity and continuity of $T$ give us
$
(T(hk))(t)=\lim_N\lim_M\sum_{j=1}^M (Th_j)(t)k(s_j)\Delta_j.
$"
This shows that  $\int T S_\tau h(t) k(\tau) d\tau$.
I concur that $T(hk)\neq (Th)*k$ as your counter examples show, but your proof and mine uses the time invariance in the next step.

Your first step is $$T \int_\tau \phi_n(t-\tau)f(\tau)d\tau = \int_\tau f(\tau) T (\phi_n(t-\tau)) d\tau.$$ Linearity and continuity are not enough for that. You need time-invariance there.
